# Writer for sl4j log level appenders

Tags: java, slf4j

When using sl4j, I would normally write debug messages using e.g. `log.debug("some message")` where `log` is a `Logger` instance.  However, I have a third party API (cannot modify) that provides methods similar to:

```
public interface Example {
    public void debugPrint();
    public void debugPrint(Writer writer);
}
```

Where the parameterless method writes to `System.out` and the other one writes to a custom writer.  Is there any way to obtain a `Writer` instance I can pass to `Example.debugPrint(Writer)` which is equivalent to writing to whatever appenders would be written by `log.debug(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

<s>If this is JDK `Writer`, you can add (write) concrete subclass which will use an appropriate `Appender`</s>

---

I'm sorry, now it looks to me, it must go other way around -- write your custom Writer, which you'll pass to `debugPrint`, having it's `Writer#write()` method implemented using configured log factory, so code outline will look like:

```
class Slf4jBackedWriter implements Writer {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Slf4jBackedWriter.class);

    @Override
    public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {            
    } // etc

}
```

Comment: The custom subclasses would have to know what filtering and appenders are configured somehow, unless I'm missing something.  The sl4j filters, appenders and backend library (e.g. logback) are all configured by external files, not known to my code.

Comment: Well, it's closer so +1.  I suppose if it accepted an external  `Logger` and an indication of which log level method to use it would be very close and could be called like `ex.debugPrint(new Slf4jBackedWriter(log, DEBUG))` assuming some enum is used for the log level.  It remains to decide when to call the sl4j API, maybe on `flush` or `close`.

Comment: @JakeCobb you may consult http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html, which tells a bit about various `*Appender` included into logback (specifically, that page says by default each log request immediatelly flushed).